# UI-Router, how to get the name of the 'state' And How send it to the function That brings Template state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, state

I start in angular

And I want to write a function that will bring template For each `state`

And just when need it. As the principle of "Lazy loading"

And after that keep it in the cache when it's the first time

I wrote this code
But I have errors, and I do not know what I'm wrong,
Some things I did not understand in angular so I understand the problematic in my code

this is all my code :

http://plnkr.co/edit/qzKJUwNImVX8EGb3ymnT?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

var getTemplate = function(name) {

  templates = {pages: 'content of pagesTemplate.html. I very wish !!'};

  if (name in templates) {
    return templates[name];
  }

  $http.get(name + 'Template.html' ).then(
    function(response){
      templates[name] = response.data;
      return templates[name];
    }
  );
};

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
  });

  $stateProvider
    .state('pages', {
      url: '/:page',

      templateUrl: getTemplate(),  // Exist in line 18 ▲ 
                // Here I want to build a function or calld a function
                // To bring me the template of the page
                // But I want it will be stored in the cache, if it comes first time
                // And next time I will take it from the cache by the name of the 'state' ('pages').

      controller: function($stateParams) {
        alert($stateParams.page);

        // And here I want to receive From the server The content of the page By $stateParams.page

      }
    })

});
```

```
<a ui-sref="pages({ page: 'home' })">Home</a>
<div ui-view=""></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [updated and working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/mYpBBTb7JbYVeTbTt4vP?p=preview)

The best we can do is to combine two great features:

1. UI-Router `templateProvider` to dynamically built template path and
2. angular **`$templateRequest`** which is so smart, that it does load and caches templates for us

here is the `templateUrl` replacement:

```
// instead of templateUrl
templateProvider: ['$templateRequest', '$stateParams', 
    function($templateRequest,$stateParams){
      var pathToTemplate = 'pagesTemplate.html';

      // do some magic with pathToTemplate

      return $templateRequest(pathToTemplate);

    }],
```

Check it [here in action](http://plnkr.co/edit/mYpBBTb7JbYVeTbTt4vP?p=preview)

And also observe these:

- [Using templateRequest in angular + typescript ($templateRequest not a function)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33123850/1679310)
- [ui router nested views condtions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33260435/1679310)

Comment: I provided you with a link to updated plunker.. it is there

Comment: There is another updated plunekr http://plnkr.co/edit/lbSagZdrQSRq2xuF55AQ?p=preview - it is now working with two states.. similiar way, hope it helps

Comment: Great to see that ;) If you think this answer helped, you can accept it. Enjoy UI-Router